# Why does Typescript doesn't check values number-enums?

Tags: typescript, enums

I noticed that if I have an enum that is composed of numbers, then basically TypeScripts allows assigning any number to the variable of such type:

```
enum EnumTestA {
    foo = 1,
    baz = 2
}

const testEnum1: EnumTestA = 4;
```

**The above compile just fine. Why?**

If I try to do the same with strings:

```
enum EnumTestB {
    foo = "FOO",
    baz = "BAZ"
}

const testEnum2: EnumTestB = "zzz";
```

Then it refuses to compile it as expected.

Comment: To support bit flags, unfortunately.  (If I get to a real computer before someone else answers this, I’ll elaborate)

Comment: @jcalz please do. Also, is there a way to make these number-enums typesafe?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15591

Comment: So they gained annotation for bit-flags and sacrificed type-safety for both number-enums and bit-flags. Sounds like a very poor decision to me. You could say that C++ had the same issue, made the more sensible decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common usage of enums is for [bit-flags](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/BitFlags.htm), which are essentially numbers with only one bit set, so their bitwise or (a single number) can be decomposed into the individual flags. If numerical values were checked, then something like the following wouldn't work:

```
enum Flags {
    FLAG1 = 1,
    FLAG2 = 2,
    FLAG3 = 4
};

const flags: Flags = Flags.FLAG1 | Flags.FLAG2;
```

And it would need a cast, which was deemed too annoying to have to deal with, so they decided to not check numerical values.

Comment: It looks like a very poor choice by whoever made this decision. So they sacrificed type safety for number-enums and didn't gain any type-safety for bit-flags, all they gained was a an annotation for bit flags. If you want an annotation you can just to `type MyFlags = number;`. Am I missing some advantage of this decision? You could say that C++ was on the same crossroad and took the other path.

Comment: This decision mainly allows for named constants in a namespace.